# How to call WordNet from Android? [Wordnet api for Android]

Tags: java, android, wordnet

I used [rita](http://www.rednoise.org/rita/wordnet/documentation/docs.htm) framework in Java to use [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). It worked fine but how can I use it in android? Is there any framework/API to access WordNet from android?

JAWS requires WordNet to be installed (on say Windows) and access it from Java! Any work around?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure about your requirements but I have been toying around with [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) hoping to use it as a dictionary source.

I discovered your issue where a number of interfaces access the installed WordNet API which won't be happening on Android.

I think I'm on to a winner with [JWI](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/) as it appears to be accessing the dictionary files directly (these can be downloaded independently on the WordNet download page)

I'll update this once I've looked further into the interface and confirm / retract this comment.

Comment: Hi mate, hope you don't mind me digging up such an old post. I wanted to ask, did you have any luck with JWI?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the [JWI](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/) API for using WordNet on Android. Most of the basic functions I have tried out - looking up a word in the glossary, getting the WordStem and different senses of the word all work. And this is straight out of the box, with minimal alterations to the code that is already there.

Comment: could you please tell me how I can set up JWI API for using Wordnet on Android? I have downloaded both JWI and Wordnet, and integrated JWI into my current project but I haven't been able to read the files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using JWI, you could copy all wordnet' files in asset directory.
Then, you should copy all files to external storage, so you can access to the dictionary.